# Implement Text Synchronization using Java

Tags: java

[Interview Question] You are working on a collaborative code editor between 2 people. I have the text
synchronizing across both screens. However, I have run into the problem
illustrated below.
[image]

Two screens were given of Person A and Person B as shown in the figure and text synchronization between the screen has been already done. But they have one problem, they are not able to synchronize the cursor positions.
So suppose in screen A cursor and cat are on line 1 and the cursor is behind the cat. So if Person A hits enter , both cursor and cat will move to line 2. Since the text is synchronized between the screens, the cat in the screen B is also being moved to the next line but the cursor in the same screen is still at line 1. So we have to synchronize the cursor position too.
We have a following method that will give us the diff between the old and new content.

```
/*Implement the fixCursorRow method don't worry about updating the column.
*/

public class Cursor {
    public int column;
    public int row;

    public Cursor(int row, int column);
}

// diff comes from the other screen.
// content is content of the current screen before diff is applied.
// cursor is the cursor of the current screen.

// diff format:
// The diff contains all content from beginning to end of document.

{{"1", "\n"}, {"0", "cat"}}
// house -> horse = {{"0", "ho"}, {"-1", "u"}, {"1", "r"}, {"0", "se"}}
// "0" -> equality, "1" -> addition, "-1" -> removal
public Cursor fixCursorRow(String[][] diff, String content, Cursor cursor) {
}
```

Note:

```
1 means addition of something
0 means nothing is changed
-1 means removal of something
```

So for this problem we get following diff array

```
{{"1", "\n"}, {"0", "cat"}}
```

So in the diff array you can see there is an addition of the new line `{"1", "\n"}` and also there is no change in the content `{"0", "cat"}`.This mean we have to move cursor to the next line.

Can anyone please explain me how to implement the `fixCursorRow`? I couldn't come up with any solution.

Comment: Why not iterating through diffs and if a '\n' is added before the cursor row, increase the cursor row and if a character is added in the cursor row before the cursor column, then increase the cursor column.
I assume that the diffs are given in order for each line of the content, right?

Comment: yes the diffs are given in order for each line